# CSV newline error after becoming .exe file using Pyinstaller

Tags: python, csv, pyinstaller

I have made a simple CSV writer using newline='' function, and open the written CSV use Os.startfile(). It works as expected when I am running it with Thonny. Here's the code:

```
import csv
from os import startfile

list1 = [
    ['1','Jun','Male'],
    ['2','Eri','Female'],
    ['3','Yuiri','Female']
]

with open('test.csv', 'w', newline='') as g:
        writer = csv.writer(g, delimiter=';')
        writer.writerows(list1)
        
startfile('test.csv')
```

But after packing it into .exe file using pyinstaller, i got some error like this:
[image: newline='' Error]

Below is the command that I used to make .exe file in pyinstaller:

```
pyinstaller --onefile csv+tkinter.py
```

Does anybody have any insight why this is happening?

Answer (score 0):

`newline` isn't an argument for `open()` in Python 2, but it is in Python 3.

Chances are you have PyInstaller set up to use Python 2, and you'll need to make it use Python 3.